# Application Pool Error and ASP.NET error

Tags: asp.net, .net, exception, application-pool

Whenever we get the below error in the IIS7.5 which is running on windows 2008 R2 64bit OS

> A process serving application pool 'app poolname' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '2388'. The data field contains the error number.

We are also getting random ASP.net error triggered after few seconds after the above error triggered.

Is there any relation between the a application pool fatal communication error and asp.net

I'm trouble shooting this for my IT department for the past 2 weeks to fix this error. The application pool error comes 2-3 times in a day which causes some users logged out.

Our application is build to run on "any CPU". Please guide to fix the issue